# Postgres How to drop all tables from a schema with "group" in name?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres database schema with dozens of tables i need to drop. I essentially need to drop all the tables in my schema (abcd) with the word "group" in the name. How do i do that without manually going in and writing drop script for each one? Wondering if there is some easy way to do that in postgres sql? or maybe using python?

`drop table abcd.group%;`

Comment: `select * from pg_class where relnamespace = 'abcd'::regnamespace and relname ilike 'group%'` will get you tables starting with group. If you want group anywhere in name then  '%group%'. You could then loop over those in Python or a Postgres function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is probably not the coolest way to do this, but you can run the query below, copy and paste the output and run that.

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || schemaname || '.' || relname || ';' "statement"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'abcd' AND relname ILIKE 'group%';
```

Comment: what is "statement"? is that a specific command in postgres?

Comment: I just can leave a column without a name.  Otherwise it has no meaning.